Two "scale" terms in "ee.Reducer.linearFit()" of Google Earth Engine. Error in the documentation?
In "ee.Reducer.linearFit()" of Google Earth Engine there are two output terms called "scale" according to the official GEE documentation. Look at
In the example it is shown that there are two "scale" terms when listing the bands in:
Map.addLayer(linearFit,
{min: 0, max: [-0.9, 8e-5, 1], bands: ['scale', 'offset', 'scale']}, 'fit');

According to the documentation one of the scales corresponds to the slope of the regression fit line.
What exactly do these two "scale" terms mean? Was it a typo? Or do they refer to something else?
complete code
// This function adds a time band to the image.
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  // Scale milliseconds by a large constant to avoid very small slopes
  // in the linear regression output.
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e18));
};

// Load the input image collection: projected climate data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-DCP30_ENSEMBLE_STATS')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('scenario', 'rcp85'))
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2006-01-01'), ee.Date('2050-01-01'))
  // Map the time band function over the collection.
  .map(createTimeBand);

// Reduce the collection with the linear fit reducer.
// Independent variable are followed by dependent variables.
var linearFit = collection.select(['system:time_start', 'pr_mean'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

// Display the results.
Map.setCenter(-100.11, 40.38, 5);
Map.addLayer(linearFit,
  {min: 0, max: [-0.9, 8e-5, 1], bands: ['scale', 'offset', 'scale']}, 'fit');


Scale refers to slope as you correctly mentioned. The output image has only two bands: scale and offset. The second scale you see in Map.addLayer is setting the visualization band channels like in RGB/false color images. They just repeated the 'scale' band in the red and blue channels so it has more weight when visualizing. Below from ee.Reducer.linearFit() documentation:
*

Returns a Reducer that computes the slope and offset for a (weighted)
linear regression of 2 inputs. The inputs are expected to be x data
followed by y data. Where applicable, the outputs are named: "scale",
"offset".




